# how can i remove the word "week" from "week 1",so that i remain with the number 1only

Tags: r

i have a big dataset, with a variable called week recorded separatly from date. the week is recorded as "week 1", now i want to get rid of the word week and remain with the number. how can i do that in r? the following is what i have. i just run the first 6, otherwise the dataset is big.

```r
>head(data1.2)
        DATE  TIME                          PLACE    ZONE TYPE.OF.CRIME   WEEK
1 2011/01/01 23:00 KIEPIES CLUB                      <NA> ARMED ROBBERY WEEK 1
2 2011/01/03 10:00 AUSSPANNPLATZ                  Zone 14 ARMED ROBBERY WEEK 1
3 2011/01/07 14:00 UNAM BUSHES                    Zone 16 ARMED ROBBERY WEEK 1
4 2011/01/08 21:34 TOTAL SERV. STATION, KHOMASDAL  Zone 9 ARMED ROBBERY WEEK 1
5 2011/01/15  <NA> WOODPALM STR 625               Zone 11 ARMED ROBBERY WEEK 2
6 2011/01/03 14:03 C KANDOVAZU STR                 Zone 5   ASSAULT GBH WEEK 1
```

Comment: Use `gsub` ....

Comment: `data1.2$WEEK <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", data1.2$WEEK))`

Comment: good. thaanks very much. can the same code work with the Zone in the very same dataset?